# Reflection principle of Brownian motion does not hold?

Tags: brownian-motion

How is **P{ B<sub>t</sub> > a | T<sub>a</sub> <= t } = 1/2** an appropriate description of the reflection principle of Brownian motion? Shouldn't the inequality in the denominator be "less than" instead of "less than or equal to"?

In the case where T<sub>a</sub> = t exactly, I would think that B<sub>t</sub> = a exactly; or, in other words, B<sub>t</sub> > a is not possible. Please see the attached plot of Brownian motion from *Probability and Random Processes* (Ramon van Handel) that visualizes B<sub>t</sub> and T<sub>a</sub>:
[p158](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmMWf.png)

Comment: This is just sloppy notation. Since $T_a$ has a continuous distribution the probabilities $P\{T_a\le t\}$ and $P\{T_a<t\}$ are identical.

Comment: Oh interesting, good to know... thank you Kurt